# How to make character not enter the platform when colliding on the side with the platform?

Tags: collision-detection, game-maker

**I had a problem with detecting my character's collision with the enemy being detected in 2 ways:**

- side by side
- when it (character) jumps into the enemy's head.

I imagine it to be basic, so I figured this question would be not only on the site but also in countless other places.

**I researched this site and found related things, but not exactly what I would like:**

[Getting 2D Platformer entity collision Response Correct (side-to-side + jumping/landing on heads)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13009/getting-2d-platformer-entity-collision-response-correct-side-to-side-jumping)

[Handling exact collisions on character controller and/or other objects in unity? (eg. head shot, chest , leg,etc)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/163430/handling-exact-collisions-on-character-controller-and-or-other-objects-in-unity)

**But because of this video I got it:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9LbutnLIj84

---

**The game I'm doing is platform, but instead of the character move, it's the platform that moves.**

**obj_Plataform - Step Event:**

```
if jump==false{
    if !place_meeting(x,y+1,obj_Player){
        vspeed=-5;
    }else{
        vspeed=0;
    }
}else{
    if contJump<20{
        contJump+=1;
    }else{
        jump=false;
        contJump=0;
    }
}
```

This is a code that causes the platform to go up when it is not in contact with the player.

And it has a condition for the platform jump (it goes down and the `jump` variable becomes true, and after the counter reaches a certain value the `jump` variable becomes false).

**My problem is that the character can not get into the platform by colliding on the side with it (The character is the white cube):**

[image]

I thought about using `place_meeting` in relation to the x-axis, but the whole platform is just an object (error), because I do not know if it would be possible to move some of dozens of tiles at the same time in the correct way.

**Plataform:**

[image]

I also tried something related in a collision event among those involved, including using the character's x, but nothing worked.

I thought a condition to prevent the platform from walking left while it is colliding with the character.

**obj_Plataform - Keyboard Event (left arrow):**

```
x-=10;
```

Above the current code to move the platform to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I understood a little more about the function `place_meeting`.

**Documentation:**

https://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/movement%20and%20collisions/collisions/place_meeting.html

**obj_Plataform - Keyboard Event (left arrow):**

```
if !place_meeting(x-7,y+3,obj_Player){
    x-=10;
}
```

With this code you prevent the platform from moving to the left if any part of it is colliding with the character.

**Two important points:**

- activate precise collision checking on the platform sprite.

[image]

- by adding a y-axis value (`y+3`), you give the platform a chance to move even if the character is a bit sunk in it.

[image]

**Value varies from project to project.**